# return first instance of unmatched regex scala

Tags: regex, scala

Is there a way to return the first instance of an unmatched string between 2 strings with Scala's Regex library?

For example:

```
val a = "some text abc123 some more text"
val b = "some text xyz some more text"

a.firstUnmatched(b) = "abc123"
```

Comment: The text isn't known ahead of time. There's a list of unique string pairs that I want to put through this kind of function

Comment: I might be misunderstanding you. The way I know to construct a regex expression is by doing `val regex = str.r` (that's the scala specific way). But `str` has to be defined at some point. I don't know where the first unmatched instance in my strings will be or anything like that.

Comment: Actually, I think I misunderstood the question. Deleting my comments. Sorry about that.

Comment: It sounds like you want a parser. You would first have to tokenize the string, and then you'd have to analyze the tokens to see if they match a legal order. That would mean you have to build a lexical analyzer and then a parser to analyze the tokens. Even that doesn't really get you all the way there, though, since you could have a problem with the lexical analyzer before you even got to the parser stage. You'd have to stream the tokens into a parser one by one and validate the order as it goes. Regex can only tell you "matched" or "not matched".

Comment: Some variation of `a.split(" ").zip(b.split(" ")).dropWhile { case (a, b) => a == b }.head._1` maybe?

Answer (score 1):

Regex is good for matching & replacing in strings based on patterns.
But to look for the differences between strings? Not exactly.

However, `diff` can be used to find differences.

```scala
object Main extends App {
  val a = "some text abc123 some more text 321abc"
  val b = "some text xyz some more text zyx"
  val firstdiff = (a.split(" ") diff b.split(" "))(0)
  println(firstdiff)
}
```

prints "abc123"

Is regex desired after all?  Then realize that the splits could be replaced by regex matching.
The regex pattern in this example looks for words:

```
  val reg = "\\w+".r
  val firstdiff = (reg.findAllIn(a).toList diff reg.findAllIn(b).toList)(0)
```